# Unable to pass responsive css to page which calls in Iframe tag in other responsive page

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I have designed a responsive page that includes a pagination block through an iframe tag but the responsive CSS is not applying for the iframe block and its content.

I have passed the CSS from main page to the iframe page, but it not applying responsive CSS.

Comment: Are you trying to style the content inside of the iframe?

Comment: Yes inside of Iframe

Comment: Ya... you can't style the inner content of an iframe.

Comment: are you sure that you have added 
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'> into iframed page ?

Comment: But, Its my own page. Is there any alternate?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0" /> in main page. @Manoj Meena. Let me try in both page once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add any style into page inside of iframe. What you must do is :

1. First, styling the page that you want to be added into iframe.
2. Then insert that styled page into iframe.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" id="responsivecss"  href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


Call these css in both main page and iframe page. But, when i check the main page in web developer responsive tool. Its not connecting to responsive.css of iframe page. Remaining design is working in responsive. Any idea about this issue. @Angga Lisdiyanto

Comment: Have you checked the page before you include it into iframe? You must test it as standalone first.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time..Let me try this and get back to you @Angga Lisdiyanto